# ¿Existe algún adjetivo en español para describir a alguien "condenado al ostracismo"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, adjetivos

En inglés existe el adjetivo "ostracized", que significa alguien condenado al ostracismo. ¿Existe un adjetivo en español para describir la misma palabra? Creo que uno derivado de *ostracismo* mismo no existe (tal vez me equivoco pero no lo pude encontrar) pero ¿alguno derivado de alguna palabra similar?

Comment: A mi lo más que se me ocurre es "rechazado", "desterrado" (que implica terrirtorio físico), "excluído" o similar, pero no encuentro traducción directa para "ostracized", que es "destierro político."

Comment: El término "ostracismo" me parece extraño.  Se ve como una creencia o un sistema de creencias.  Pero yo pienso que cuando alguien ha sufrido el ostracismo, lo importante es la acción de excluir. // Propongo: **marginado**.

Comment: @aparente001 Tambien exiliado

Comment: Entiendo que destierro _político_ no es de residencia, así que le va bien  _ninguneado_.

Comment: @cdlvcdlv, ¿por qué no lo escribes en una respuesta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pesar de que la palabra *[ostracismo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=RJhVdm5)* se documenta en español desde el siglo XVI, de hecho proviene del griego clásico, y sin embargo nunca se ha documentado ningún derivado. Dado que su significado es "destierro político", y de *destierro* tenemos *desterrado*, esa es precisamente la voz que se ha usado como adjetivo.

Ejemplo:

> *Dícese que para reunir estas fuerzas y preparar su empresa, cuenta el general Flores con el ausilio de su amigo el general Santa Cruz, ex-presídente de Bolivia, y también desterrado político que ha marchado de Burdeos á Madrid.*
>
> **El Español (Madrid).** 11/10/1846, n.º 703, [página 2](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0003512674&page=2).

Otro:

> *Fué el primero el señor Domínguez Alfonso, canario prestigiosísimo, el que se
>   vio desterrado de la política de su país; [...].*
>
> **La Acción (Madrid. 1916).** 16/4/1916, [página 2](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0003463836&page=2).

No encuentro nada que pueda expresar la misma idea en una palabra. Ya si quieres, lo suyo sería inventar un neologismo derivado de *ostracismo*, como *ostracizado* u *ostracismado*, pero no tengo claro cuál sería el más respetuoso con la etimología, así que lo he consultado con la RAE. Su respuesta ha sido la siguiente:

> En español pueden emplearse *condenado al ostracismo*, *aislado*, *desterrado*, *discriminado*, *excluido* o *relegado* para traducir la forma inglesa *ostracized*. Ahora bien, el verbo *ostracizar* cuenta con alguna documentación en Google y su formación sería válida; incluso su origen griego (*ostrakízo*) permite justificar su empleo en algunas lenguas modernas, como el inglés (*ostracize*), el francés (*ostraciser*), el italiano (*ostracizzare*) y el portugués (*ostracizar*).

Si el verbo *ostracizar* tiene justificación válida desde el punto de vista etimológico, su participio *ostracizado* sería la palabra que buscas.

Comment: Yo creo que _ostracizado_ se puede proponer etimológica y léxicamente, pero es difícil de pronunciar como él solo. Un trabalenguas con _ostracizar_ sería más difícil que el clásico del cielo enladrillado: "El político está ostracizado...".

Comment: El primer ejemplo no lo veo tan claro. Si un ex-presidente boliviano "*ha marchado de Burdeos á Madrid*" cabe interpretar *desterrado político* en el sentido literal de *exiliado por motivos políticos*.

Answer (score 5):

"**óstraco**"

Lo anterior, considerando la etimología de la palabra:

> Ostracon u Ostrakon (del griego: ὄστρακον óstrakon, cuyo plural es ὄστρακα, 
>   óstraka) es una concha o fragmento de cerámica sobre el que se escribía el 
>   nombre del ciudadano condenado al ostracismo.

... y por la manera en que se "españoliza" el sufijo "-kon" del griego. Ej: "zoon politikon" --> (el animal) político.

Sin embargo, es una palabra construída que no se usa (y que puede usarse). Habitualmente al que sufre ostracismo le llamamos "desterrado".

Comment: Bienvenido a SSE. Magnífica primera aportación. Solo tengo una puntualización: ¿no debería ser _**óstraco**_? Por la pronunciación griega que das, porque "ostra" en español lleva el acento en la "o" y por semejanza con _político_.

Comment: Debí haber puesto la tilde. Edito la respuesta y la agrego.